# Importing a project into Eclipse and deploy it in your local

Tags: java, eclipse, accurev, eclipse-oxygen

I have a project in Accurev for which I created a workspace. I did File > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace. After the import, the first thing that I have done is Configure Build path (Project>properties>Java Build Path). Still, I can find a lot of errors. I'm new to Java and I'm searching the Java errors in google and fixing them. Please suggest, How can I solve the similar errors for multiple files.

For Example,

1. The Empty block should be documented (I have it in 3 files)
2. The parameter customerExpression should not be assigned ( Multiple files )
3. The import java.util.List is never used ( Multiple files ). There are some other imports which were used inside the company are never used.

Apart from Java Problems, I do have

1. Classpath Dependency Validator Message
2. EJB Validator Message
3. HTML, JSP Problems etc which I feel can be solved once I solve Java Problems. I was told that Java problems are important. COrrect me if I'm wrong.

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: the here listed messages are all warnings, not errors. These can be turned off in global or project specific settings.

Comment: Can you please be specific and if possible give an example @CarlosHeuberger

Comment: Those Java messages are warnings, the others sound more severe.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Carlos Heuberger said these are seems like warnings not errors they won't cause any problem for your project to run. People usually don't care that much of warnings.

If you want to get rid of those warnings eclipse have quick fix actions for some of them. To do that head one of the warnings and right click then select quick fix. This should pop out a screen which summarize the action that eclipse will take.

Or you can simply hide them.

If you want to hide all the validation warnings go `Window>Preferences>Validation` then click `Disable All` button. This will disable all validation messages in your workspace.

For java warnings go through `Windows>Preferences>Java>Compiler>Errors/Warnings` and change the warning  options according to your preferences. In my workspace under the `Code Style` section `Undocumented empty block` is setted to ignore so i don't get that warning in my workspace unlike yours.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and it helped me in understanding about the warning and how to deal with them. @murateca